# Show chat window when new message received

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to build chat system. The problem is when one user types the message to another the chat window won't display instantly with that message to the receiver. Only after the receiver refreshes the window everything works fine. Here is my current code:

profile.php

```
setInterval(function(){
    var username="<?php echo $username; ?>";
    $.ajax({
        url:"s/shower.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:"shower=" + username,
        success:function(data){
                if (data == 1){
                    $(".pchat").show();
                }
        }
    });
},500);

$(".chat_wind").click(function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    var newid=id.split("chat_wind");
    var datid=newid[1];

    $(".pchat").show();

});


$(".chatform").submit(function(){
    var parent=$(this).attr("id");
    var split=parent.split("chatform");
    var newid=split[1];

    var val=$("#chati").val();
    if (val.length == 0){
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:"s/log.php",
        type:"post",
        data:"newid=" + newid + "&txt=" + val,
        success:function(data){
            setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"s/chat.php",
                    type:"post",
                    data:"username=" + newid,
                    success:function(w){

                        var objDiv = document.getElementById("cbody");
                        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
                        $("#cbody").html(w);
                    }
                });
            },500);
        }
    });

    $("#chati").val("");
    return false;
});
```

chat.php

```
<?php
    include "db.php";
    include "timeago.php";

    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $dat='';
        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat where uchated='$username' ORDER BY time asc");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
            $time=$row['time'];
            $txt=$row['text'];

            $dat.="
                <div id='msg'>
                $txt <div id='ctime'></div>
                </div>";

        }
        echo $dat;
    }

?>
```

shower.php

```
<?php
    include "db.php";
    if (isset($_POST['shower'])){
        $shower=$_POST['shower'];

        $sqlara=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat where uchated='$shower'");

        $numara=mysql_num_rows($sqlara);

        if ($numara == 0){
            echo "0";
        }else{
            echo "1";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Use $("#cbody").append(w); instead of $("#cbody").html(w);

Answer (score 1):

You need to use websockets to implement chat system. I dont know php. you can try this link http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket to understand websocket programming

Comment: websockets and socket.io (incase of node.js backend) are the best solution for real-time chat.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need you can go for WebSocket and Server-Sent Events which are supported in HTML5. But for a start **long polling** would be ok. Then you can understand the requirements of your Chat site and upgrade.

[Read more on these methods (link).](http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery)